# Dropdown menu isn't working

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a Menu where it has four dropdown buttons that aren't working. The following image shows how it is supposed to work: "*Bijutaria*=(perfumes+fios)"
"*Inserir*=(*Perfumes*=homem+mulher)+*Bijutaria*=fios+pulseiras)"

[image]

I think the problem is located in my CSS code, but I'm not being able to figure out what the problem is.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 150px;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #E2144A;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="left" class='column'>
  <li><a href="ver.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bijutaria</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="pulseiras.php">Pulseiras</a>  </li>
    <li><a href="fios.php">Fios</a>  </li>
  </ul>
  <li><a href="#">Perfumes</a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="prfh.php">Homem</a></li>
      <li><a href="prfm.php">Mulher</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Inserir</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Perfumes</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="insrph.php">Homem</a></li>
        <li><a href="insrpm.php">Mulher</a></li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Bijutaria</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="insrp.php">Pulseiras</a></li>
        <li><a href="insrf.php">Fios</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not valid html `<li><a href="#">Bijutaria</a></li>
  <ul>` - you have the nested(?) UL outside the LI - you need to remove some `</li>` from before the next `<ul>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your code that I fixed, you should always have an UL around LI and not pu UL inside UL or LI inside LI

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 150px;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #E2144A;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<ul id="left" class='column'>
  <li><a href="ver.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bijutaria</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="pulseiras.php">Pulseiras</a>  </li>
      <li><a href="fios.php">Fios</a>  </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Perfumes</a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="prfh.php">Homem</a></li>
      <li><a href="prfm.php">Mulher</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>   
  <li><a href="#">Inserir</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Perfumes</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="insrph.php">Homem</a></li>
          <li><a href="insrpm.php">Mulher</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Bijutaria</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="insrp.php">Pulseiras</a></li>
          <li><a href="insrf.php">Fios</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified your HTML so it was valid. I then rewrote your CSS, adding the absolute basics to do what you're looking for with flyouts:

Here's a functioning JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/La068t6d/1/

HTML:

```
<ul id="left" class='column'>

    <li><a href="ver.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bijutaria</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="pulseiras.php">Pulseiras</a></li>
            <li><a href="fios.php">Fios</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Perfumes</a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="prfh.php">Homem</a></li>
            <li><a href="prfm.php">Mulher</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Inserir</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Perfumes</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="insrph.php">Homem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="insrpm.php">Mulher</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Bijutaria</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="insrp.php">Pulseiras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="insrf.php">Fios</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { list-style-type: none; }
ul,li {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;

    }
    a {
        padding: 5px 8px;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #fff;
    }



#left {
    width: 150px;
}
#left > li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    display: none;
    }
    #left li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid, you put Li inside LI, I will up your answer once it's fixed

Comment: Will fix it now. Perhaps I missed something. Sorry. Please give me a minute and I'll update the HTML both in my post as well as at JSFiddle.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple Pure CSS Drop Down Menu</h1>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul >
  <li><a href="ver.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bijutaria</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="pulseiras.php">Pulseiras</a>  </li>
    <li><a href="fios.php">Fios</a>  </li>
  </ul>
    </li>
  <li><a href="#">Perfumes</a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="prfh.php">Homem</a></li>
      <li><a href="prfm.php">Mulher</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Inserir</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Perfumes</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="insrph.php">Homem</a></li>
        <li><a href="insrpm.php">Mulher</a></li>
      </ul>
        </li>
      <li><a href="#">Bijutaria</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="insrp.php">Pulseiras</a></li>
        <li><a href="insrf.php">Fios</a></li>
      </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is horizontal. Now what OP wanted

Comment: Your HTML is not valid